# Python Selenium Error: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, element

I have a client that wants to web scrape some information from a website. The loop works the first time but the 2nd time the error occurs. Any help? I also do not recommend going to the actual website, its sketchy.

Code:

```
URL = 'https://avbebe.com/archives/category/高清中字/page/5'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=options)
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5)

Vids = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-thumbnails-link')))
for title in Vids:
    time.sleep(3)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-thumbnails-link')))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", title)#Where error occurs
    time.sleep(5)
    VidUrl = driver.current_url
    VidTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-69331"]/h1/a').text
    try:
        VidTags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tags')
        for tag in VidTags:
            VidTag = tag.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
        
    except NoSuchElementException or StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass

    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        fieldnames = ['Title', 'Tags', 'URL']
        thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        thewriter.writeheader()
        thewriter.writerow({'Title': VidTitle, 'Tags': VidTag, 'URL': VidUrl})
    driver.get(URL)
    print('done')
```

Error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Full Terminal Traceback:

> done Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\Heage\Coding\Freelancing\Clients\Genewang-webscrape\main.py",
> line 24, in 
> driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", title)   File "C:\Users\Heage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 634, in execute_script
> return self.execute(command, {   File "C:\Users\Heage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Heage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
> (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the normal click method, store the element in the list, get the element index and click on the index.

you can update your code with the below one

```py
video_text = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("entry-thumbnails-link")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-thumbnails-link')))
video_text[0].click()
```

The complete code will look like this

```py
Vids = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-thumbnails-link')))
for title in Vids:
    time.sleep(3)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    video_text = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("entry-thumbnails-link")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-thumbnails-link')))
    video_text[0].click()
    time.sleep(5)
    VidUrl = driver.current_url
    VidTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-69331"]/h1/a').text
    try:
        VidTags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tags')
        for tag in VidTags:
            VidTag = tag.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text

    except NoSuchElementException or StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass

    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        fieldnames = ['Title', 'Tags', 'URL']
        thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        thewriter.writeheader()
        thewriter.writerow({'Title': VidTitle, 'Tags': VidTag, 'URL': VidUrl})
    driver.get(URL)
    print('done')
```

Also try not to use these many sleep().